# не могу решить задачу из ЕГЭ на метод префиксных сумм. помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, алгоритм

У медицинской компании есть N пунктов приёма биоматериалов на анализ. Все пункты расположены вдоль кольцевой автомагистрали длиной N километров на расстоянии 1 км друг от друга. Известно количество пробирок, которое ежедневно принимают в каждом из пунктов. Пробирки перевозят в специальных транспортировочных контейнерах вместимостью V пробирок. Каждый транспортировочный контейнер упаковывается в пункте приёма и вскрывается только в лаборатории. Компания планирует открыть лабораторию в одном из пунктов. Стоимость перевозки биоматериалов равна произведению расстояния от пункта до лаборатории на количество контейнеров с пробирками. Для развоза контейнеров к двум соседним пунктам прикреплены две машины, которые, двигаясь в противоположных направлениях, собирают все контейнеры от пункта старта до лаборатории. Из пункта, где располагается лаборатория, стоимость доставки равна нулю. Лабораторию расположили в одном из пунктов приёма таким образом, чтобы стоимость доставки контейнеров у каждой машины была одинакова. Найдите номер пункта, где нужно расположить лабораторию, чтобы стоимость доставки у каждой машины была одинаковая. Если таких пунктов несколько, укажите наибольший номер такого пункта.

Номера пунктов совпадают с порядком в файле и нумеруются с нуля.

Входные данные:
Даны два входных файла (файл A и файл B), содержит в первой строке число N (2 ≤ N ≤ 5 000 000) — количество пунктов приёма биоматериалов, и число V (1 ≤ V ≤ 1000) — вместимость транспортировочного контейнера. Каждая из следующих N строк содержит одно натуральное число: количество контейнеров в пункте. Пункты расположены в порядке следования на трассе.

Пример входных данных:

```
6 10
6
50
25
63
60
39
```

При таких исходных данных (вместимость транспортировочного контейнера равна 10 пробирок) лабораторию можно открыть в пункте на втором километре (5 + 1⋅2 + 4⋅3 = 7 + 6⋅2) и на пятом километре
(6 + 7⋅2 = 1 + 5⋅2 + 3⋅3).

**оригинал:** https://education.yandex.ru/ege/task/ea729ca3-bf26-46cb-b7d8-1b4b46dd1038

правильные ответы: 27A.txt - 96; 27B.txt - 892584

моё решение (работает при чётном N):

```
import math
a = open('test.txt')
n, v = map(int, a.readline().split())
a = [math.ceil(int(x) / v) for x in a]

left = suml = right = sumr = 0
length = n // 2

for i in range(1, length):
  left += a[-i] * i
  suml += a[-i]
  right += a[i] * i
  sumr += a[i]
  
if(abs(left - right) == a[length] * length): print(0)

for i in range(1, n):
    suml += a[i - 1] - a[i - length]
    left += suml - a[i - length] * (length - 1)
    
    right += a[(i + length - 1) % n] * (length - 1) - sumr
    sumr += a[(i + length - 1) % n] - a[i]
    
    if(abs(left - right) == a[(i + length) % n] * length): print(i)
```

проверял его на примере из задачи:
a = [1, 5, 3, 7, 6, 4]
i - позиция лаборатории
left - сумма доставки слева
right - сумма доставки справа
center - стоимость доставки до пункта, который находиться на одинаковом расстоянии от лаборатории, как слева, так и справа
| i | left | right | center |
|---|------|-------|--------|
| 0 |  16  |  11   |   21   |
| 1 |  9   |  17   |   18   |
| 2 |  7   |  19   |   12   |
| 3 |  13  |  14   |   3    |
| 4 |  13  |  6    |   15   |
| 5 |  20  |  11   |   9    |

вроде всё правильно получается (подходят пункты: 2, 5).
но ответ для 27A получается 84, вместо 96
подскажите пожалуйста где я ошибаюсь
заранее спасибо

файл 27A.txt:

```
100 13
58
94
81
91
74
3
63
95
83
24
60
22
63
39
68
29
86
63
6
104
49
31
46
71
30
55
113
48
103
109
68
71
55
41
71
103
47
71
51
112
96
86
93
22
45
15
6
36
94
88
15
73
61
30
85
8
20
90
86
12
95
88
114
76
81
25
74
38
2
58
45
95
17
101
7
6
56
24
102
17
54
8
46
61
29
38
59
108
2
72
99
12
62
32
60
84
99
52
104
110
```

Comment: я являюсь homoops и на данный вопрос я могу ответить как.
Посмотрите на 6 строчку, там у вас и скрывается ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как сказал homoops ошибка скрывается на 6 строчке, а именно в том что balvan учитывает лишь 2 варианта доставки из n - 1.
но если учесть все варианты доставки то можно получить правильный ответ.
вот доказательство:

```
import math
a = open('27B.txt')
n, v = map(int, a.readline().split())
a = [math.ceil(int(x) / v) for x in a]

suml = left = right = sumr = 0
for i in range(1, n):
    left += a[-i] * i
    suml += a[-i]
start = 0
for i in range(n):
    if(i != 0):
        start -= 1
        right -= sumr
        sumr -= a[i]
        suml += a[i - 1]
        left += suml
        
    mn = abs(left - right)
    while(start < n - 1):
        start += 1
        if(mn < abs(left - a[(i + start) % n] * (n) - right)): 
            start -= 1
            break
        suml -= a[(i + start) % n]
        left -= a[(i + start) % n] * (n - start)
        sumr += a[(i + start) % n]
        right += a[(i + start) % n] * start
        mn = abs(left - right)
    if(mn == 0): print(i)
```